# Stuck in fullscreen?

Tags: interface

Ok, so I wanted to show my friend my video I was working on in blender. I go to the preview window and hit "fullscreen" (or something like that). So now I am stuck in this full screen mode. I have tried:

- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Down arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Up arrow</kbd>
- <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Z</kbd>
- <kbd>F11</kbd>

Nothing has worked. Here is my file.

[image]

Comment: try F11 or "`window` > `toggle window fullscreen`"

Comment: how do i do the window thing?

Comment: I hit F11 and moved my mouse to the top right , you will get an icon click on it

Comment: Can you describe what you did to "Go to the preview window?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only keystroke you haven't listed in your question is <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> which will fullscreen a panel (more than just maximizing with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Space</kbd>). Press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>F11</kbd> again to toggle fullscreen.

Be sure to try both. It might be possible to fullscreen and maximize at the same time, which would make it so that undoing one doesn't change much unless you also undo the other. I'm not sure how that works (and I don't have Blender in front of me), but it's worth keeping in mind.

Comment: its not in full screen mode its just that int he blender window it is the only thing you can see.

Answer (score 3):

I am supposed to hit <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd>

Comment: If you are using Linux, Alt-F10 is a system hotkey.  I disabled it as described here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/131359/how-do-i-enable-the-alt-f10-f9-shortcuts.   I don't think that worked, but hitting it several times rapidly did work.